# How to save value to a column with array datatypes in ios using parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2

I have class User Inside that i have column "favorites" with datatypes array.I want to save multipal "ObjectId" in "favorites" column.Image of class User

[image: User class Image]

I find out solution for store the multipal value in Favorites column but i still not get any proper solution.How can i store ObjectId In "favorites" column using parse.com